# In the telegram-iOS source code, change the qrcode's corner radius. how this blow code working? I'm tied

Tags: telegram, core-graphics

this code , explain find the valid data, then scan the four direct to determine it's cornradius. but I dont't find how to change it, just memcopy data. how to explain it ?

```
func drawAt(x: Int, y: Int, fill: Bool, corners: UIRectCorner) {
                if !fill && corners.isEmpty {
                    return
                }
                
                for i in 0 ..< scaledSquareSize {
                    var dst = context.bytes.advanced(by: (scaledPadding + y * scaledSquareSize + i) * context.bytesPerRow + (scaledPadding + x * scaledSquareSize) * 4)
                    let srcOffset = (fill ? 0 : scaledSquareSize * 4)
                    let src = tmpContext.bytes.advanced(by: i * tmpContext.bytesPerRow + srcOffset)
                    
                    if corners.contains(i < scaledSquareSize / 2 ? .topLeft : .bottomLeft) {
                        memcpy(dst, src, halfLen)
                    } else {
                        memcpy(dst, src + blockLen, halfLen)
                    }
                    dst += halfLen
                    if corners.contains(i < scaledSquareSize / 2 ? .topRight : .bottomRight) {
                        memcpy(dst, src + halfLen, halfLen)
                    } else {
                        memcpy(dst, src + blockLen + halfLen, halfLen)
                    }
                }
            }

for y in 0 ..< size {
                        for x in 0 ..< size {
                            if (y < markerSize + 1 && (x < markerSize + 1 || x > size - markerSize - 2)) || (y > size - markerSize - 2 && x < markerSize + 1) {
                                continue
                            }
                            
                            var corners: UIRectCorner = []
                            if valueAt(x: x, y: y) {
                                corners = .allCorners
                                if valueAt(x: x, y: y - 1) {
                                    corners.remove(.topLeft)
                                    corners.remove(.topRight)
                                }
                                if valueAt(x: x, y: y + 1) {
                                    corners.remove(.bottomLeft)
                                    corners.remove(.bottomRight)
                                }
                                if valueAt(x: x - 1, y: y) {
                                    corners.remove(.topLeft)
                                    corners.remove(.bottomLeft)
                                }
                                if valueAt(x: x + 1, y: y) {
                                    corners.remove(.topRight)
                                    corners.remove(.bottomRight)
                                }
                                drawAt(x: x, y: y, fill: true, corners: corners)
                            } else {
                                if valueAt(x: x - 1, y: y - 1) && valueAt(x: x - 1, y: y) && valueAt(x: x, y: y - 1) {
                                    corners.insert(.topLeft)
                                }
                                if valueAt(x: x + 1, y: y - 1) && valueAt(x: x + 1, y: y) && valueAt(x: x, y: y - 1) {
                                    corners.insert(.topRight)
                                }
                                if valueAt(x: x - 1, y: y + 1) && valueAt(x: x - 1, y: y) && valueAt(x: x, y: y + 1) {
                                    corners.insert(.bottomLeft)
                                }
                                if valueAt(x: x + 1, y: y + 1) && valueAt(x: x + 1, y: y) && valueAt(x: x, y: y + 1) {
                                    corners.insert(.bottomRight)
                                }
                                drawAt(x: x, y: y, fill: false, corners: corners)
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I read the code, But I can't build the telegram code. so I haven't debug this. just read.
I want somebody can explain it